# ¿Porque no puedo visualizar un archivo pdf proveniente de una api?

Tags: api, flutter, postman

Hola estoy usando la libreria flutter cached_pdfview para poder visualizar un pdf al hacer tap en un elemento. aca el codigo

```
class PdfScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int? id;
  String? titulo;
  String? contenido;
  String? descripcion;
  MutimediaLeccion? multimediaLeccion;

  PdfScreen({
    super.key,
    this.id,
    this.titulo,
    this.contenido,
    this.descripcion,
    this.multimediaLeccion,
  });

  @override
  State<PdfScreen> createState() => _PdfScreenState();
}

class _PdfScreenState extends State<PdfScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontsizeT = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.050;
    final fontsizeS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.040;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.multimediaLeccion!.data.first.tipoArchivo),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: const PDF(
          enableSwipe: true,
          autoSpacing: true,
          pageFling: true,
        ).cachedFromUrl(
          widget.multimediaLeccion!.data.first.archivo
              .toString(), // URL del PDF
          //'http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',

          placeholder: (progress) =>
              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          errorWidget: (error) => Center(child: Text(error.toString())),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

como pueden ver de este objeto (multimediaLeccion) se obtiene el pdf.
aca les mostrare el json que devuelve para que vean su estructura .

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "Proceso Exitoso!",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "titulo": "LECCIÓN NÚMERO UNO",
            "descripcion": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's  type specimen book. ",
            "contenido": "CONTENIDO UNO",
            "estado": true,
            "fechaCreacion": "2023-07-13T07:48:21.000Z",
            "mutimedia_leccion": {
                "status": 200,
                "sms": "proceso exitoso",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "titulo": "prueba pdf",
                        "archivo": "94e9fb2f-cbf8-44e3-aa55-08e7f4dd322c.pdf",
                        "estado": true,
                        "createdAt": "2023-08-23T01:13:05.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-08-22T20:13:05.165Z",
                        "tipoArchivo": "pdf"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "titulo": "LECCIÓN DOS",
            "descripcion": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
            "contenido": "CONTENIDO DOS",
            "estado": true,
            "fechaCreacion": "2023-08-23T01:15:24.000Z",
            "mutimedia_leccion": {
                "status": 200,
                "sms": "proceso exitoso",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "titulo": "prueba HTML",
                        "archivo": "<h1>HOLA MUNDO!</h1>",
                        "estado": true,
                        "createdAt": "2023-08-23T01:16:01.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-08-22T20:16:01.528Z",
                        "tipoArchivo": "html"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "titulo": "LECCIÓN  tres",
            "descripcion": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
            "contenido": "CONTENIDO video tres",
            "estado": true,
            "fechaCreacion": "2023-08-22T20:44:42.000Z",
            "mutimedia_leccion": {
                "status": 200,
                "sms": "proceso exitoso",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "titulo": "text",
                        "archivo": "<p>texto nuevo</p>",
                        "estado": true,
                        "createdAt": "2023-08-22T20:54:28.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-08-22T20:54:28.912Z",
                        "tipoArchivo": "html"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

como pueden ver siento que estoy accediendo al pdf de forma correcta inclusive cachedFromUrl recibe un string y estoy haciendo el parseo. en todo caso obtengo lo siguiente : "invalid arguments(s)  no host specified in URI 94e9fb2f-cbf8-44e3-aa55-08e7f4dd322c.pdf.

aqui dejo las capturas por si algo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
muchas gracias

Comment: Donde proviene este json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema está en que no estás proporcionando un URI válido, en su lugar , estás haciendo uso de un identificador que parece válido, pero no es un URI de por sí

La uri que estás usando es la siguiente:

```
"94e9fb2f-cbf8-44e3-aa55-08e7f4dd322c.pdf"
```

Y debería estar en el siguiente formato:

```
"https://www.dominio.com/descargas/?archivo_id=94e9fb2f-cbf8-44e3-aa55-08e7f4dd322c.pdf"
```

o

```
"https://192.168.1.7/descargas/?archivo_id=94e9fb2f-cbf8-44e3-aa55-08e7f4dd322c.pdf" (en caso de que estés usando una API local)
```

No olvides que debes tener un endpoint en tu Backend que te permita descargar los archivos PDF haciendo uso del identificador.

```
class _PdfScreenState extends State<PdfScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontsizeT = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.050;
    final fontsizeS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.040;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.multimediaLeccion!.data.first.tipoArchivo),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: const PDF(
          enableSwipe: true,
          autoSpacing: true,
          pageFling: true,
        ).cachedFromUrl(
          'https://www.dominio.com/descargas/' + widget.multimediaLeccion!.data.first.archivo.toString(), // URL del PDF
          //Ahora se está concatenando la parte principal del dominio para que sea un URL válido

          placeholder: (progress) =>
              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          errorWidget: (error) => Center(child: Text(error.toString())),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias eso era